# JavaScript var Keyword Required?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. Do you *need* to declare the `var` keyword? It appears with the following codes below you don't have to. When do I need to and when do I don't have to use the `var` keyword? It is it just good practice to use the `var` keyword?

Without `var` keyword:

```
function sample(a,b) {
  result = a + b;
  return(result);
}
output = sample(10,20);
document.write(output);
```

With `var` keyword:

```
   function sample(a,b) {
      var result = a + b;
      return(result);
    }
   var output = sample(10,20);
   document.write(output);
```

Comment: No, `a` and `b` are locally scoped to the function at that point. You could simply `return a + b;`

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for this. didn't know there was another question similar!